# Using SQL in a Sharepoint 2007 workflow

Tags: sql, sharepoint-2007, workflow

I'm not sure this is the right forum for this, but here goes:

I'm creating a workflow that kicks off when a user submits an InfoPath form to a form library on a Sharepoint 2007 platform.  The workflow should find the manager of the user that submitted the form from SQL and email that person for approval before the next step is run.  Is this possible in Sharepoint 2007 or is using SQL in a workflow only a feature of Sharepoint 2010?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

http://sharepointdiva.wordpress.com/2009/03/10/using-sql-inside-workflow/

Comment: The date of the article is 2009. SharePoint 2010 was released on 2010. So I am pretty sure it's for SharePoint 2007.